# PowerQuery Negative Numbers

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a "value" column in my excel which have positive / negative numbers in it (depending on the input given in multiple excel sheets).

Because input can be different and output has to be negative i'm trying to find a way to make make the value column negative only.

Is there a way to make:

- Negative numbers - Stay Negative
- Positive Number - Make Negative?

Comment: FYI: 

Some values have to be positive (based on description).
I think i do know a way to all fix tis, but i want to make it as efficient as possible as its quite a large file already and don't want to make that much slower.

Comment: You can use a custom column and `-Number.Abs([your field])` to make all numbers negative.

Comment: Was looking for such an ez fix, thanks!

Comment: If you want condition based on description then just add to Rory's suggestion `if [YourDescColumn] = "Desired description" then [your field] else -Number.Abs([your field])`